# Show Different Widgets/Views on Landscape and Portrait

Tags: android, orientation, landscape, portrait

I have

Portrait Mode: 
- Containing View Pager with 2 Tabs (which contains 2 Fragments both having different views and inflating 2 different layouts.

Landscape Mode:
- Containing View Pager with 3 Tabs (which contains 3 Fragments all having different views and inflating 3 different layouts.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean in `values-land` that is set to true and `false` in values.

```
<resources>
    <bool name="is_landscape">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Depending on the value of this boolean, you can set different Fragments in your adapter.

Comment: This doesn't work completely, I have just tried it. The problem is the app crashes as the values-land variable are only accessible if the app is in landscape mode..

        Code:
        if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)){
              //code
        }else {
            //code
        }


      Log:
       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID    #0x7f070006
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
        at   android.content.res.Resources.getBoolean(Resources.java:796)